# Azure SDK - List Subscription Diagnostic Settings

Tags: azure, sdk

I want to use this API: [Subscription Diagnostic Settings - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/subscription-diagnostic-settings/list?tabs=HTTP), But I have not been able to find it in the Azure SDK.
Tried to looking into the `@azure/arm-monitor` but found only `DiagnosticSettings` which do not apply to the subscription resource, moreover they don't even have the same return type. I do not know where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, the following is correct:
Use the `diagnosticSettings` list function and in the `resourceUri` it should be `subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`:

```
const credentials = ...
const subscriptionId = ...

const monitor = new MonitorClient(credentials, subscriptionId)

const resourceUri = 'subscriptions/${subscriptionId}'

const subscriptionDiagnosticSettings = monitor.diagnosticSettings.list(resourceUri)
```